# How to get the Rejected/Pending status from Stripe Connected Account object?

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to save the status of my connected account of Stripe in my db, but Stripe doesn't return the status of the connected account, to find it we need to collect it from its fields.

For the status `isRestricted` for example we need to collect the fields

```
const isRestricted = account.requirements?.disabled_reason ? true : false && (account.requirements?.currently_due?.length > 0 
|| account.requirements?.past_due?.length > 0);
```

How to determine from the stripe fields that the status is Rejected/Pending (I have other statuses like `IsEnabled`, `isComplete`, `IsRestricted`, `IsRestrictedSoon`)?

For rejected I think i have solved it, the answer I gave is below, and for  status Pending also. You can comment about possible mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

For the case of rejected account. I think i found it, you need to check for requirements field and its field disabled_reason  `requirements: { disabled_reason: 'rejected.other'}` 
 The disabled_reason string must contain the value rejected

Also for pending, you need to check
`account.requirements?.pending_verification.length > 0;`

If these methods have any problem you can comment below

Comment: Yep correct. And for `pending` you want to look at `requirements.pending_verification`: https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-requirements-pending_verification

Comment: I should i check ```requirements.pending_verification``` array is greater than 0  or should i check for specific values in this array?

Comment: ```const isPending = account.requirements?.pending_verification.length > 0;```

Comment: Up to you really. Feel free to test this out using the Connect Test values: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing